# A question about $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity

Tags: continuity, epsilon-delta

How can I prove the $f(x)=x^{\frac{2}{3}}-1$ is continuous on $[ -1, 1 ]$. First I wrote the expression for continuity on $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ language. So, $\forall \varepsilon>0$, $\exists \delta>0$ if $x_{1}\in [-1, 1]$ and $|x_{1}-x|<\delta$, then $|f(x_{1})-f(x)|<\varepsilon$. I tried so much but I ultimately get cubic deltas so I couldn't write delta as a function of epsilon. Thanks

Comment: What you wrote is the definition for uniform continuity, which in this case is equivalent to continuity because $[-1,1]$ is compact. Continuity is defined in a point, so you must prove that $f$ is continuous in every $x_0 \in [-1,1]$ and the definition would be $\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists \delta >0$ such that if $x \in [-1,1]$ and $|x-x_0| < \delta$ then $|f(x)-f(x_0)| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Sorry, yes you are right I will fix it. Thanks

Comment: But, indeed I can't catch the answer:

Comment: "...but I ultimately get cubic deltas...".  Although it is true that $\delta$ must be expressed in relation to $\epsilon$, you are also allowed to add an **arbitrary additional** constraint, such as $0 < \delta \leq 1 \implies \delta^3 \leq \delta.$  This type of **contrivance** allows you to simplify the relationship between $\delta$ and $\epsilon$.  If the desired expression for $\delta$ is something like $\delta = f(\epsilon)$, then you would combine the constraints by: $\delta \leq \min[1, f(\epsilon)].$

Comment: Thanks for helping! It was beneficial!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, continuity is about one point. What you are trying to prove seems to me like uniform continuity, which is a different thing. Luckily, continuous functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous, so you can do both. So let's prove uniform continuity (which implies continuity).

Fix $\epsilon >0$ arbitrarily small. I say that $\exists \delta$ such that if $x_1 , x_2 \in [-1,1]$ with $|x_1 - x_2 | < \delta$ then
$|f(x_1)- f(x_2 )|< \epsilon$.

We have $$|f(x_1)- f(x_2)|= |(x_1)^{2/3} - (x_2)^{2/3}|=|(x_1)^{1/3} - (x_2)^{1/3}||(x_1)^{1/3} + (x_2)^{1/3}| \leq 2 |(x_1)^{1/3} - (x_2)^{1/3}|$$

Now you can use the identity $a^3 - b^3 = (a-b)(a^2 + b^2 + ab)$ and it should do the trick. I mean that you multiply and divide by $(x_1)^{2/3} + (x_2)^{2/3} + (x_1)^{1/3}(x_2)^{1/3}$ so that on the numerator you have $x_1 - x_2$ and on the denminator something which you can easily estimate.

Comment: Oh understand, so by then I can use the identity and attain number from interval with knowing that $x_{1}$ has a bound on the interval, say $1$. Isn't it?

Comment: Yeah something like that. Be careful with the estimate of the denominator though. Show that it doesn't mess things up

Comment: Okay thank you very much! I will give a try!

Comment: You're welcome!